# How can we redirect using htaccess and DNS together with Google Sites?

Tags: redirects, dns, 301-redirect, google-sites

I have updated a site and some of the old links are no longer referring to the right place (404). I wonder how I can do it through DNS and `.htaccess`.

As I understand Sites does not support redirecting of links like this: example.com/hey-there.html to example.com/welcome (301 redirect).

I am therefore looking to combine Sites with a redirect through DNS settings if that is possible. I have several DNS records active currently which verify ownership of the site (TXT, CNAME and one Web forward of example.com to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)). Now, is it somehow possible to have a redirect of these queries.

Could you please help me out on how this can be done?

Comment: You can't do redirects using DNS unless the domain names are different (and even then, all the DNS server can do is point to another web server which does the actual redirects.  (TXT records don't help, and CNAME records don't do redirection.  Web forwards are not a function of DNS)  I have no knowledge of Google sites, but I'd be rather suprised if they honour .htaccess files.   Have you seen https://support.google.com/sites/thread/114066289/how-to-have-a-page-redirect-to-a-different-site?hl=en - which seems to tell you how to set up redirects.

Answer (score -1):

To get you started here is a rule in `.htaccess` to redirect `example.com/hey-there.html` to `example.com/welcome`

```
# Code generated by www.301-redirect.online
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^example\.com/hey\-there\.html$ /example.com/welcome? [R=301,L]
```

You can use [Htaccess Redirect Generator](https://www.301-redirect.online/htaccess-rewrite-generator) to generate more of them.  Note it does not work with wildcards and I am not associated with it.

Comment: Google sites doesn't support `.htaccess` so while these rules work on most hosts, they are useless in the context of Google sites.